# Initializing var type in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

**Question**: How do I initialize **var** in the following code? [Then, of course, I'll remove `var` declaration from the **if** statement]

The last line of the following code returns the well know error: `The name lstCurrent does not exists in current context`. Clearly the error is because the **var** is defined inside **if** statement and used outside **if** statement

**Note**: I'm selecting only a few columns from the table and hence dealing with anonymous type. Some examples I saw online did not work - probably since my code is selecting anonymous type. But this is just a guess.

```
var lstCurrent =????;

if(Type==1)
  var lstCurrent =_context.Customers().Where(t =>t.type=="current").Select(c => new { c.LastName, c.City});
else
  lstCurrent  = _context.Customers().Where(...).Select(...)

return View(lstCurrent.ToList());
```

Comment: What is the name of the variable you declared? It is missing in your code example...

Comment: Use the back-tick for `inline code`, not double asterisk (**bold**).

Comment: You could use a ternary operator instead of if statement.

Comment: IEnumerable<object > lstCurrent = new List<object>(); ?

Comment: What type is the parameter to `View()`? Use that type. Or if that's `List<X>`, use `IEnumerable<X>`.

Comment: Also: `else
  _context.Customers().Where(...).Select(...)` -- In your original code, were you doing something with the results of that select?

Comment: @elgonzo That was a typo. I've corrected it after reading your question -thank you. Variable name is same as in if statement: `lstCurrent `

Comment: @EdPlunkett I'm just passing `lstCurrent.ToList()` in the view. In the `else` statement also I am setting `lstCurrent  = _context.Customers.Where(..).Select(...)`. I've just added `lstCurrent`  for more clarification.

Comment: @nam Yeah I figured it was just a copy error. Thanks for the update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var` is not a type - it means "I don't care to (or can't) specify what the type is - let the compiler do it for me".

In your case, you're assigning it the result of one of two queries, one of which returns an anonymous type, so you *can't* specify the type since you don't know the name of the anonymous type (hence the term "anonymous").

In order to use `var`, the compiler needs some expression at initialization to know what the actual type is.

I'd suggest something like:

```
var lstCurrent = Type==1 
              ? _context.Customers().Where(t =>t.type=="current").Select(c => new { c.LastName, c.City})
              : _context.Customers().Where(...).Select(...)
```

But note that your "selects" must return the same type (or anonymous types with the exact same fields) or you won't be able to use `var`.

In the end I would try to bake the condition into your `Where` clause for less repetetive code:

```
bool isTypeOne = Type==1;

var lstCurrent = _context.Customers()
                         .Where(t => isTypeOne ? t.type=="current" : ...)
                         .Select(c => new { c.LastName, c.City})
```

Comment: In real scenario I've three conditions with `if(...){...}else if(..){..}else{...}` statement. I was thinking that suggested solutions would work for three conditions as well. How do I expand your suggestion to three conditions case? However, I've marked your response as an Answer since you've, in fact, answered to what I asked (based on my example.)

Comment: You can chain the ternary `? :` operator: `Where(t => checkOne?  conditionOne : (checkTwo ? conditionElse : conditionTwo)))`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
IEnumerable lstCurrent;
if(Type == 1)
    lstCurrent = foo;
else
    lstCurrent = bar;
```

Comment: Using the non-generic `IEnumerable` would prevent the `ToList` call from compiling.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I initialize var in the following code? [Then, of course, I'll
>   remove var declaration from the if statement]

This is not possible since the type of the object you assign at the left should be known. For instance

```
var a = "text";
```

The type of `a` is known at compile time since the right hand expression is a `string`. This cannot be done with a sequence of anonymous types, like the one you define.

I can see two options. One is that D Stanley already mentioned. The other is to define a class with two properties like below:

```
public class PersonCity
{
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
}
```

and then project each element of your query to a `PersonCity` object.

```
lstCurrent context.Customers()
                  .Where(t =>t.type=="current")
                  .Select(c => new PersonCity
                  { 
                      LastName = c.LastName, 
                      City = c.City
                  });
```

Doing so, you can define now you `lstCurrent` as below:

```
var lstCurrent = Enumerable.Empty<PersonCity>();
```

**Important Note**

In case of your queries return different types, the above are *meaningless*. Both queries (one in if and the other at else) should return the same type.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common *trap* when expecting to use an implicit type declaration or when refactoring code that already has an implicit type (`var`). The [current accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43944329/1690217) is very much valid but reducing all expression variations into a single 1-liner linq expression can easily impact on readability of the code.

The issue in this case is complicated by the projection to an anonymous type at the end of the query, which can be solved by using an explicit type definition for the projection, but it is simpler to break up the query construction into multiple steps:

```
var customerQuery = _context.Customers().AsQueryable();
if (Type == 1)
    customerQuery = customerQuery.Where(t => t.type == "current");
else
    customerQuery = customerQuery.Where(...);
... // any other filtering or sorting expressions?

var lstCurrent = customQuery.Select(c => new { c.LastName, c.City});
return View(lstCurrent.ToList());
```

or of course that last segment could have been a one liner or if there are no further references to `lstCurrent` the compiler may optimise that into the following:

```
return View(customQuery.Select(c => new { c.LastName, c.City}).ToList());
```

> In this example I have deliberately cast to `IQueryable<T>` to ensure this solution is compatible with both `IQueryable<T>`/`DbSet<T>` contexts and repository style `IEnumerable<T>` contexts.

---

This variation is usually the first that comes to mind, but we are still declaring the source of the query in two places, which increases the ambiguity of this code and the risk of divergence in later refactoring (by accidentally editing only one branch and not maintaining the code in the other branch):

```
IQueryable<Customer> customerQuery = null;
if (Type == 1)
    customerQuery = _context.Customers().Where(t => t.type == "current");
else
    customerQuery = _context.Customers().Where(...);
... // any other filtering or sorting expressions?
var lstCurrent = customQuery.Select(c => new { c.LastName, c.City});
return View(lstCurrent.ToList());
```

---

A different solution is to explicitly define the output as its own concrete class:

```
public class CustomerSummary
{
    public string LastName { get;set; }
    public string City { get;set; }
}
...

List<Customers> customers = null;
if (Type == 1)
    customers = _context.Customers().Where(c => c.type == "current")
                                    .Select(c => new CustomerSummary
                                    {
                                        LastName = c.LastName,
                                        City = c.City
                                    }).ToList();
else
    customers = _context.Customers().Where(c => ...)
                                    .Select(c => new CustomerSummary
                                    {
                                        LastName = c.LastName,
                                        City = c.City
                                    }).ToList();
... // any other filtering or sorting expressions?
return View(customers);
```

It's a lot of code for a once-off, but if you make it abstract enough it could be re-used for other scenarios, I would still combine this with the first code example, that keeps the source, filter and projection logic separated, over the lifetime of an application these 3 elements tend to evolve differently, so separating out the code makes refactoring or future maintenance easier to complete and review.